# How would I query a MySQL database, if given a huge list of data to try to find out the best suited results?

Tags: mysql, database, search

Scenario: I have a MySQL database of people and all their various features as attributes. Then I also have a huge file which lists (line-by-line) attributes which describes a particular person. This result should narrow down all people who match/have these characteristics.

Questions:

How do I query the database on a line-by-line file, to get results from that database into a single view?

What approach do I take to interface my database with this type of querying?

What is the best overall approach to this problem given the circumstances?

**Example of file:**

```
male, brown hair, green eyes, height 6" age 12
female, blonde hair, blue eyes, height 5'9" age 33
male , black hair, brown eyes, height 5'6" age 13
male, brown hair, brown eyes, heigh 6'1" age 34
```

**Database:**

Contains table with attributes for all fields

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches?

Comment: You should load the file into a table, for starters... then actually try something.  Report back if you have issues.

Comment: AT Marcus Adams; Not exact matches just a list returned of possible matches

Comment: as Fosco stated, try to pull in yourself... however, the example file format... what happens if you are missing certain elements... are there still place-holder values?  Will they ALWAYS be in the same order, or will they be staggered... how / where it is populated from... too many variables at this point.

Comment: AT DRapp - Attributes which are not present will be understood as null. The data coming in will be copacetic and parsing the data into the database isn't a concern. The crux of my problem is how to run some type of statistics against the database to display results most closely matching a specific line, line-by-line. Does that make sense? I apologize if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How do I query the database on a line-by-line file, to get results from that database into a single view?
```

Well Actually here are the optimal steps

1) Open file

2) Convert lines to array

3) For each element in the array use a threaded function that converts the required characteristics to SQL Statement

4) Send the query to the query handler (ill explain later on)

```
What approach do I take to interface my database with this type of querying?
```

For optimal performance you will need to have a database class that will que the statements. I don't know the language you're onto but you will max out the performance if your class is able to work in this logic:

1) Each new statement goes on a que

2) Before executing a statement, use prepare statement against the database

3) After executing the statement, save the results somewhere and then execute the next statement

```
What is the best overall approach to this problem given the circumstances?
```

Best approach is using a fast and OO capable interface for connecting to the database and loading the whole file in memory so that you will minify the disk overhead. I strongly suggest to load the database on a ramdisk if you have enough ram.